# Append Prefix to Field

Tags: mongodb

I have several documents such as:

```
    {
    "_id" : "60d3fcb6077b0a41e090ecc9",
    "vendor" : "Best",
    "test_name" : "Number Sequence",
    "discipline" : "early math"
},
{
    "_id" : "60d3fcb6077b0a41e090edd7",
    "vendor" : "Best",
    "test_name" : "Value Places",
    "discipline" : "early math"
}
```

I would like to append `EM:` to the `test_name` field, regardless of what is already in that field as long as it matches the `vendor` and `discipline` fields.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
db.getCollection("assessments_1234").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "vendor" : "Best",
                "discipline" : "early math"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$set" : {
                "test_name" : {
                    "$cond" : {
                        "if" : {
                            "$regexMatch" : {
                                "input" : "$test_name",
                                "regex" : /.* /
                            }
                        },
                        "then" : {
                            "$replaceOne" : {
                                "input" : "$test_name",
                                "find" : "",
                                "replacement" : "EM: "+"$test_name"
                            }
                        },
                        "else" : "$test_name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    {
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
).forEach(function(record) {
    print(record.test_name)
   db.assessments_1234.replaceOne({_id: record._id}, record)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can work the update with the aggregation pipeline, which directly perform the update in the MongoDB server, without the need to fetch the record to the backend and update them one by one back to the MongoDB server.

1. For the string concatenation, you should use `$concat` operator.
2. As you want string concatenation, you should not need the `$replaceOne` operator.

```
db.getCollection("assessments_1234").update({
  "vendor": "Best",
  "discipline": "early math"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "test_name": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$test_name",
              "regex": ".*"
            }
          },
          "then": {
            $concat: [
              "EM: ",
              "$test_name"
            ]
          },
          "else": "$test_name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1yDlgYVVcX1)

As you mentioned that you want to update the `field_name` without concern its value, perhaps you can simplify the query without the need of `$cond` operator.

```
db.getCollection("assessments_1234").update({
  "vendor": "Best",
  "discipline": "early math"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "test_name": {
        $concat: [
          "EM: ",
          "$test_name"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo (without `$cond`) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sWNEXCJn9J5)

Comment: Both solutions seem to be really close, however the test_name field is being updated to"EM: Number SequenceNumber Sequence" rather than "EM: Number Sequence"

Comment: Hi @Jake, sorry for the mistake. I revised the answer. Thanks.